# Parse a string with several separators

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to implement a calculator to become a bit more familiar with Objective-C. I have a string entered by the user which could be something like "41*92". What would be a good way to parse the string to add the 2 numbers to an array? Something like componentsJoinedByString: but with four different separators at this stage (+,-,*,/)?

Comment: "I'm trying to implement a calculator to become a bit more familiar with XCode" - you rather mean "Objective-C" or "the OS X or iOS SDK", no?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`

`NSArray *arr = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-*/"]];`

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string like @Sean said, but if you want to actually *parse* an input like `41*92`, the way to do it is usually to use [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSScanner). See Apple's [String Programming Guide: Scanners](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html) or search for *NSScanner tutorial*, there are plenty.

(You can also "cheat" using [NSExpression](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/) if you'd like to evaluate math expressions, but I guess that's not what you want.)